# How to freeze TFBertForSequenceClassification pre trained model?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

If I am using the tensorflow version of huggingface transformer, how do I freeze the weights of the pretrained encoder so that only the weights of the head layer are optimized?

For the PyTorch implementation, it is done through

```
for param in model.base_model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Would like to do the same for tensorflow implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it. Freeze the base model BEFORE compiling it.

```
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model.layers[0].trainable = False
model.compile(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging this thread [1](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/400) up, I think the following codes won't hurt for TF2. Even though it may be redundant in a specific case.

```
 model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('./bert-base-uncase')
 for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
    for w in layer.weights: w._trainable=False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
for _layer in model:
    if _layer.name == 'distilbert':
        print(f"Freezing model layer {_layer.name}")
        _layer.trainable = False
    print(_layer.name)
    print(_layer.trainable)
---
Freezing model layer distilbert
distilbert
False      <----------------
pre_classifier
True
classifier
True
dropout_99
True

Model: "tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
distilbert (TFDistilBertMain multiple                  66362880  
_________________________________________________________________
pre_classifier (Dense)       multiple                  590592    
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_99 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 66,955,010
Trainable params: 592,130
Non-trainable params: 66,362,880   <-----
```

Without freezing.

```
Model: "tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
distilbert (TFDistilBertMain multiple                  66362880  
_________________________________________________________________
pre_classifier (Dense)       multiple                  590592    
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_59 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 66,955,010
Trainable params: 66,955,010
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Please change from TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification to TFBertForSequenceClassification accordingly. To do so, first run `model.summary` to verify the base name. For TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification, it is `distilbert`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively:

```
model.bert.trainable = False
```